# rgba on all pages and element style

Tags: html, css

I would like to set an overlay on my site:

When I play around with the color in the inspect window, I can make it work in the element style like this:

```
element.style {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

I tried to add the line `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);` , in my body css, but it is not working. Should it not be on the body element?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

body {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by an overlay, **specifically**?  I don't see much sense in having an alpha channel on your `body` background, unless you also have a background on your `html`?  Show the relevant code and an example of what you're trying to do, in the question.

Comment: That is the relevant code. The code for the overlay is also in my question, the explanation where the overlay is working is also in my question, the link to my site is also in my question, the inspect window also exist on my website.

Comment: is it just me or "overlay" and body background is not the same thing? and also - this css should work fine as a body background.

Comment: @NeKr There's no HTML here.  How can you ask a question that you've tagged as HTML/CSS with absolutely no HTML in your question?  The link to your site is irrelevant.  If you took 2 minutes to read the help page (http://stackoverflow.com/help), you'd know this.  Stack Overflow is for questions that others will find useful in the future.  We're here to teach and help people learn, not just be your coding service.  Your site will be fixed some day (perhaps today), and then your question is useless to others unless you **put the code in the question**, which is required by the rules of the site.

Comment: happy with the html now?... That is the relevant html code.

Comment: @NeKr If that's the relevant code, then I really have no idea what to tell you.  You never did clarify what you mean by overlay.  (That can really mean a lot of things, and since there's nothing on your page, I don't know what you're overlaying on top of what.)

Comment: As I wrote in my question it is working how I want it in the inspect window: element.style {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

Comment: an overlay is something that lays over. body background is not an overlay. that's why noone gets your question. plus that background css is fine. it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about overlaying color on your bg img then the rgba needs to be in the same css block as the img

```
body {
    background-image: bgimg.jpg;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct approach. The website in question has its background image (well, images) in a jQuery slider plugin called Supersized. If I were @NeKr, I would pull out the slider plugin (since it's not really being used like one right now anyway) and put in the code that this answer recommends.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answers and feedback. Yes it is a very good idea to do. In the past I had 3 images sliding, but not anymore. I actually totally forgot the images were in a slider. But how would I give the background image the same effect, as it has now? I would like that the background image is not moving like it is now. I just tried add the background picture in css instead, but the background picture is following you when you scroll.